# How to call onResume() of Fragment

Tags: android

I used Navigation drawer , with number of fragments.
I want to call onResume() of fragment , Where i need to load updated data from server.

Comment: **I want to call onResume() of fragment**, Override `onResume()` in fragment

Comment: @Raghunandan..i tried it not working....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`onResume()` will be called when your **`Activity onResume()`** is called, you don't have to call `onResume()` in a `Fragment`.

Read this to understand the [`Fragment Lifecycle`](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle)

If you want to do it from your `Fragment` you should do something like this

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //OnResume Fragment
    }
```

Also if you have to do something general you can do it on your `Activity` it's the same as the `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

You can still achieve whatever you want to with `onResume()` in a fragment using `onHiddenChanged()`. Below is a sample method:

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    if(hidden)
        //Windup;
    else
        //initialize;
}
```